# MySQL multiple group_concat with count per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table (place_analytics) and I want to fetch count per month group by place_id using group_concat,

[image]

I have tried this,

```
SELECT place_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(created_at), '%m'))
) AS months,
COUNT(*) AS place_count
FROM place_analytics
GROUP BY place_id
```

which gives me almost right result as,

[image]

If you look into the row number three, which is,

```
place_id | months      | place_count
4        | July, June  | 2
```

the count is a sum of all months i:e July, June.

**Question:** 
Is there any way where I could get count for every month using group_concat, something like below,

```
place_id | months      | place_count
4        | July, June  | 1,1
```

OR this format will also work,

```
place_id | months_and_count
4        | July,1 SEPARATOR June,1





CREATE TABLE `place_analytics` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `place_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_followed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of place_analytics
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('1', '10', '6', '0', '2017-06-01 15:45:04');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('2', '98', '1', '1', '2017-06-01 15:45:39');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('3', '98', '3', '1', '2017-06-01 15:46:24');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('4', '10', '5', '1', '2017-06-01 17:51:27');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('5', '98', '5', '1', '2017-06-01 17:53:48');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('6', '98', '5', '1', '2017-06-08 15:43:27');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('7', '1', '5', '1',  '2017-06-08 15:47:56');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('8', '2', '5', '1',  '2017-06-08 16:00:43');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('9', '4', '5', '1',  '2017-06-09 16:21:19');
INSERT INTO `place_analytics` VALUES ('10', '4', '2', '1', '2017-07-13 14:29:45');
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh, I am sorry for that, I have edited my questions with the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Z.place_id,GROUP_CONCAT(Z.place_count),GROUP_CONCAT(Z.months) months
FROM
(
    SELECT place_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(created_at), '%m'))
    ) AS months,
    COUNT(*) AS place_count
    FROM place_analytics
    GROUP BY place_id,MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(created_at), '%m'))
)Z
GROUP BY place_id
```

Try above query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT p.place_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(p.created_at), '%m'))
) AS months,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM place_analytics GROUP BY place_id, MONTH(created_at)
) a)  AS place_count
FROM place_analytics p
GROUP BY place_id;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ad87d/1/0)**.